# Why does iCal always show days of the week and months of the year in English?

Tags: macos, ical

I have iCal open in Italian, and for some reason the months and days of the week continue to show up in English. Is there some way to get it to run entirely in Italian?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the system preferences > language & text > region needs to be set to Italy before the months & days of the week show up in Italian. Fortunately this can be accomplished without changing the language of the entire computer.